# use pip install command in recipes Yocto Project

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I need to use an existing library on this site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

library present format compressed SpeechRecognition-3.4.3.tar.gz

can I use

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

in overrider functions like 
do_fetch , do_install in recipe file ?

To install this library in the image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `inherit pypi` instead.Quite likely you also want to use `setuptools`, ie

```
 inherit pypi setuptools
```

See for example the `python-flask` recipe: [python-flask_0.10.1.bb](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-flask.inc)

Comment: Note that pypi.bbclass is part of meta-python not oe-core, so you'll need to add that layer to your bblayers.conf.

Comment: The python-flask recipe no longer exists at that link.

Comment: [Here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-virtualization/tree/recipes-devtools/python/python-flask_0.10.1.bb?h=master) is an active link to the python-flask recipe.

Comment: pypi.bbclass is now part of oe-core: [link](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/pypi.bbclass)

Comment: And, it doesn't work.  It's broken from back about two years ago and nobody seems to have fixed it.  When PyPI changed how they provide content dynamically, it broke everything.